# Why does python make mistake in basic arithmetic calculations?

Tags: python

Try to calculate the following on python shell:

```
>>> 5.3-2.7
2.5999999999999996
>>> 2.8-2.7
0.09999999999999964
>>> 4.7-2.8
1.9000000000000004
>>> 4.3-2.5
1.7999999999999998
>>>
```

Why does it happen?
How can I prevent this problem from making bugs in my code?

Comment: Please read this:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: This is not an error but a limitation of floating point arithmetic. Google floating point arithmetic for many articles that can explain what's going on.

Comment: Worth taking a look at [the Python tutorial on floating point](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) as well.

Comment: Basically, floating point numbers are not completely accurate.

Answer (score -2):

It's not a bug, but you can do this.

```
>>> round(5.3 - 2.7, 1)
>>> 2.6
```

Comment: Meh.. Downvote me all you want, maybe someone is interested in actually seeing the result they expect.

Comment: Maybe, someone is interested in actually understanding what's happening, or how to deal with numbers other than in the example, like with more than one digit after the period.